How to detect offending field in "Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list'" error
I have a TypeORM in Node.js project connecting to Mysql database.
I am experiencing Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list' error.
The main question is how to detect the offending variable associated with a given sql column.  This is especially when the actual query being sent to the database seem correct as illustrated below.
In some reporting I have come across, the error likely to occur when one of the variables used in building SQL query, is sending 'NaN' to the database. An example is a case reported here. In this reporting, the offending field was identified by adding debug: true to createPool function then re-running and reviewing the output.
In my case, I enable logging in typeorm and is able to see below:
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO `coop`(`coop_id`, `coop_guid`, `coop_name`, `coop_description`, `doc_id`, `coop_type_id`, `cd_geo_location_id`, `coop_count`, `coop_members_count`, `coop_saves_shares`, `coop_loans`, `coop_assets`, `coop_member_penetration`, `coop_date_label`, `coop_woccu`, `coop_reserves`, `coop_ref_id`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, DEFAULT) -- PARAMETERS: ["","Ethiopia","2022",19369,null,21328,6916853,711228785,173329666,807692307,9,"2022-12-31 23:59:59",0,null]
query failed: INSERT INTO `coop`(`coop_id`, `coop_guid`, `coop_name`, `coop_description`, `doc_id`, `coop_type_id`, `cd_geo_location_id`, `coop_count`, `coop_members_count`, `coop_saves_shares`, `coop_loans`, `coop_assets`, `coop_member_penetration`, `coop_date_label`, `coop_woccu`, `coop_reserves`, `coop_ref_id`) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, DEFAULT) -- PARAMETERS: ["","Ethiopia","2022",19369,null,21328,6916853,711228785,173329666,807692307,9,"2022-12-31 23:59:59",0,null]
error: Error: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list'
query: ROLLBACK

When the above is compared with the actual create script for the table shown below, every column seem to be correct:
CREATE TABLE `coop` (
  `coop_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `coop_guid` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coop_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coop_description` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doc_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `coop_type_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `cd_geo_location_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `coop_count` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `coop_members_count` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `coop_saves_shares` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `coop_loans` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `coop_assets` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `coop_member_penetration` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coop_date_label` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `coop_woccu` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coop_reserves` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `coop_ref_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`coop_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Additionally below is the typeorm model associated with the table:
import {
    Entity,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
    Column,
} from 'typeorm';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';



/// ColumnNumericTransformer
export class ColumnNumericTransformer {
    to(data: number): number {
        return data;
    }
    from(data: string): number {
        return parseFloat(data);
    }
}

@Entity(
    {
        name: 'coop',
        synchronize: false
    }
)
export class CoopModel {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn(
        {
            name: 'coop_id'
        }
    )
    coopId?: number;

    @Column({
        name: 'coop_guid',
        length: 36,
        default: uuidv4()
    })
    coopGuid?: string;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'coop_name',
            length: 50,
            nullable: true
        }
    )
    coopName: string;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'coop_description',
            length: 60,
            default: null
        })
    coopDescription: string;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'doc_id',
            default: null
        }
    )
    docId?: number;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'coop_type_id',
            default: null
        }
    )
    coopTypeId?: number;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'cd_geo_location_id',
            default: null
        }
    )
    cdGeoLocationId?: number;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'coop_count',
            default: null
        }
    )
    coopCount?: number;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'coop_members_count',
            default: null
        }
    )
    coopMembersCount?: number;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'coop_saves_shares',
            default: null
        }
    )
    coopSavesShares?: number;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'coop_loans',
            default: null
        }
    )
    coopLoans?: number;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'coop_assets',
            default: null
        }
    )
    coopAssets?: number;

    @Column(
        'numeric', {
        name: 'coop_member_penetration',
        precision: 7,
        scale: 2,
        default: null,
        transformer: new ColumnNumericTransformer(),
    })
    coopMemberPenetration: number;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'coop_date_label',
            default: null
        }
    )
    coopDateLabel?: string;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'coop_woccu',
            default: null
        }
    )
    coopWoccu?: number;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'coop_reserves',
            default: null
        }
    )
    coopReserves?: number;

    @Column(
        {
            name: 'coop_ref_id',
            default: null
        }
    )
    coopRefId?: number;


}


Does this answer your question? Programming error: Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list' while connecting to MySQL with Python

I had reviewed that case and noted that the error was also reflected in the sql script. In my, case the sql script being sent to database seem correct yet the 'NaN' error was still being reported. That is why I am asking if there is some other way of detecting the offending field.

The case is also a cvs to mysql using python and suggested solution is also python specific. My case is node.js connected to mysql via typeorm.

I don't think this is an sql or mysql issue as NaN value must have come from node.js, since mysql does not have the concept of NaN. Somewhere aling your way your model expects a number, does not receive a number,  raises the NaN error, which triggers a mysql error

This is to confirm that the issue was arising as mentioned above by @Shadow. Some fields were expecting int but the input data was set as "" (empty string). Such fields were changed to null. But the question was how to detect: I just tested each field one by one. I wish there was a better way of detection eg using typeorm logging output.
